Am I supposed to pass an empty string an argument to mark a function as interactive?
I am creating an interactive command like this:
emacs_value func = env->make_function(env, 0, 0, hello_world, "Returns 'hello world'", NULL);
emacs_value symbol = env->intern(env, "hello-world");
emacs_value args[] = {symbol, func};

The documentation for make_interactive is not clear on what should be passed as the spec, so I just made one with an empty string like this:
emacs_value spec = env->make_string(env, "", 0);
env->make_interactive(env, func, spec);

In ELisp, (interactive) does not have any arguments, so what should actually be in the spec for make_interactive?

If you read the two links within the documentation line your question-link points to, namely,

22.2.1 Using interactive
22.2.2 Code Characters for interactive

We see that interactive may have arguments.  One such type of arguments as listed in "22.2.2 Code Characters for interactive" is P. I. e., the raw prefix argument.
22.12 Prefix Command Arguments gives,
(defun display-prefix (arg)
  "Display the value of the raw prefix arg."
  (interactive "P"); <---- See the argument passed to interactive?
  (message "%s" arg))

Run C-u 9 M-x display-prefix and you'll see 9 in the minibuffer.

When they said "(interactive) does not have any arguments" they meant the literal lisp code (interactive) is a form with no arguments -- as opposed to, say, (interactive "P") which does have an argument.  The question is: What is the C code module equivalent of the specific form (interactive).

I think I've arrived at a solution. The documentation for make_string says it will accept a NULL input.
Not sure if this is the best way but this works: emacs_value spec = env->make_string(env, NULL, 0); which I can then pass to make_interactive. I guess this is close enough to how Elisp code is written.

@Sasquatch Please consider M-x report-emacs-bug with an improvement to the documentation.
